# openUrl to spotify app - in songs page

Tags: ios, spotify, openurl

In swift or objective c to open the spotify app from my own app, i do like this (swift version):

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL("spotify:")
```

I know how to go to a specific track, artiste, playlist , etc (`spotify:track:...`, `spotify:artist:...`). But it is possible to open the "Songs" view?

Answer (score 0):

for iOS there is no url.

---

for OSX the 'url' is `spotify:collection-songs`

Comment: why? :) sure it is an an answer - it doesn't work it seems.

Comment: @DamienRomito sorry took it from the OSX spotify app and assumed it would transfer